# Export Feature Class to Geodatabase without SubTypes

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, arcgis-10.5, subtype

I want to export a feature class to a geodatabase using arcpy and strip out any subtypes.  But they keep hanging around in the new feature class.  How do I get rid of them?  This doesn't work:

```
subtypes = arcpy.da.ListSubtypes(featureClass)
arcpy.RemoveSubtype_management(featureClass, subtypes)
```

The above throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\SCAT\Scripts\test.py", line 112, in <module>
arcpy.RemoveSubtype_management(featureClass, subtypes)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 17276, in RemoveSubtype
raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/49329236/820534

Comment: [ListSubtypes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-data-access/listsubtypes.htm) returns a dictionary so you need to get a list of subtype codes from that to supply to [RemoveSubtype](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/remove-subtype.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arcpy.da.ListSubtypes()` function returns a dictionary.

> The keys of the dictionary are the subtype codes, and the values of
>   the dictionary are the subtype properties.

```
subtypes = arcpy.da.ListSubtypes(r'C:\temp\data.gdb\Water\Fittings')

subtypes.keys()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

The `Remove Subtype` GP tool can accept a list of subtypes codes. You can choose what codes you would like to remove

```
arcpy.RemoveSubtype_management(in_table="C:/temp/data.gdb/Water/Fittings", 
subtype_code=[code for code in subtypes.keys() if code in [0,1,2]])
```

or just delete all the codes:

```
arcpy.RemoveSubtype_management(in_table="C:/temp/data.gdb/Water/Fittings",
subtype_code=subtypes.keys())
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion to delete all the codes, but this error was thrown:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\SCAT\Scripts\CreateShorelineFromSelectedPolylines.py", line 114, in <module>
    arcpy.RemoveSubtype_management(shoreline, subtype_code = subtypes.keys())
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 17276, in RemoveSubtype
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000192: Invalid value for Subtype Code
Failed to execute (RemoveSubtype).`

Comment: @spaine, can you please print out the `subtypes.keys()`?

Comment: Hi Alex, I think I solved the problem - I was iterating this through 2 datasets.  It worked correctly on the first one that had subtypes, but the 2nd one did not.  So the value for `subtypes.keys()` was `[0]`, which apparently is not a valid parameter for `RemoveSubtype`